# SQL Nested Multiple Select Statement

Tags: sql, vba, select, nested, recordset

Im trying to create a nested SQL statement with multiple Nested Select Statements, to be used on a record set import in excel vba.

What i want to do is create something like:

```
SELECT
    N.LimitN,
    Sum(N.amountN),
    Sum(N1.amountN1)
FROM (
    SELECT year as yearN, Sum(amount) as amountN, limit as limitN
    FROM table1
    WHERE year = 2013
    GROUP BY year, limit) as N
JOIN (
    SELECT year as yearN1, Sum(amount) as amountN1, limit as limitN1
    FROM table1
    WHERE year = 2014
    GROUP BY year, limit) as N1
ON N.LimitN = N1.LimitN1
GROUP BY N.LimitN
ORDER BY N.LimitN;
```

So that if my Raw data is like this:

```
Year       Amount        Limit
2013        100           20
2013         90           30
2013        120           40
2013          5           20
2013        100           30
2013        105           40
2013        150           50
2014        115           20
2014         50           30
2014         95           40
2014        110           50
2014         30           20
```

My Resulting Table/record set will be like this:

```
Limit     AmountN (i.e. 2013)   Amount N1 (i.e. 2014)
 20               105                    145
 30               190                     50
 40               225                     95
 50               150                    110
```

Thanks in Advance

Peter

Comment: What issue are you having with what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like you're overcomplicating the query a little, what you want is just a year wise sum of `amount`, grouped by `limit`. This can be done using a `CASE`;

```
SELECT 
  limit, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN year=2013 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) amountN,
  SUM(CASE WHEN year=2014 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) amountN1
FROM myTable
GROUP BY limit
ORDER BY limit;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e6c0/2).

(if we're talking Access here, you will need to use [`IIF`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php) instead of `CASE`)

Comment: B-E-A-UTIFUL!
Didn't even pop into my mind to use CASE WHEN.
Thanks Joachim